# JDBC preparedstatement convert control character to question mark

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

A problem is occurring when inserting a `control character(/u0096)`. The `preparedstatement` is converting it to `"?".` 
But it occurs only in some cases.

It happens in these two cases:

```
"– Varmer å få prisen"
"Hestnes – et industrieventyr"
```

In all other uses of this character it does nothing and insert the "-" in the database.

I tried to convert it to normal "-", but with same results.

```
    PreparedStatement prepStmt = makeInsertNewsItemStatement();

        for ( NewsItem item : uniqueItems ) {
            try {
                if ( !resultSet.next() ) { 
                    prepStmt.setString( 1, item.getTitle() );
                    prepStmt.setString( 2, item.getDescription() );
                    prepStmt.setString( 3, item.getLink() );
                    prepStmt.setInt( 4, item.getFeedId() );
                    prepStmt.setTimestamp(  
                           5, item.getPubDate() == null ? 
                                    new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()) : 
                                    new Timestamp( item.getPubDate().getTime() ) );                
                    prepStmt.setString( 6, item.getAuthor() );               
                    prepStmt.setString( 7, company.getCompanyId() == 20 ? null : item.getPictureUrl() );

                    prepStmt.executeUpdate(); 
                }                

            } catch ( SQLException ex ) {
                Logger.getLogger( MasterDbController.class.getName() ).log( Level.SEVERE, null, ex );
                continue;
            }
...


private PreparedStatement makeStatement( String sql ) {
        PreparedStatement prepStmt = null;
        try {
            prepStmt = companyConnection.prepareStatement( sql );
        } catch ( SQLException ex ) {
            Logger.getLogger( CompanyDbController.class.getName() ).log( Level.SEVERE, null, ex );
        }
        return prepStmt;                
    }

    private PreparedStatement makeInsertNewsItemStatement() {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO App_FeedEditor_NewsItems"
                + "(title, ingress, url, feed_id, published, source, picture_url)"
                + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        return makeStatement( sql );       
    }
```

The character is in item.title()

Comment: Um, U+0096 is *not* a dash. It's a control character.

Comment: The encoded representation of the - character is \u002d , \u0096 seems to be a control START OF GUARDED AREA .

Comment: What is your database, and is it prepared to receive unicode ?